# Relationship between initializtion and definition

Tags: c++, initialization, definition

Could you explain how does object definition bounds with the variable initialization, denoting initialization.

```
#include <iostream>
int a = 5; //definition

int main{ std::cout << a; }
```

sec. 1.8/1:

> An object is created by a definition,[...]

`a` is statically initialized to `5`. Initialization occurs as a part of an object definition, or it is independent from definition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From §7/8:

> A definition causes the appropriate amount of storage to be reserved and any appropriate initialization (8.5) to be done.

So yes, a definition causes initialization.

However, initialization (and object creation in general) can be caused without a definition, which is described by the omitted part of your quote (§1.8/1):

> An object is created by a definition (3.1), by a new-expression (5.3.4) or
>   by the implementation (12.2) when needed.

Comment: Thank you for normative reference.

Answer (score 0):

An object's life time begins after its initialization has completed. It is not possible to define an object without initializing it. Even if you say `int a;`, you define and initialize `a`, although this particular kind of initialization (called "default-initialization") does nothing and leaves the object `a` uninitialized.